# Azure pipelines copy specific wiki pages to folder inside build artifact

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-wiki

We have wiki page with release notes, where every subpage is per version. Using Azure pipelines, how can I extract those subpages into pdf files inside the build artifact?

The idea is that the App will read them from its directory and display them to the user.

I've done some search but I cannot seem to find a solution.

Comment: Do you know about "[Publish a Git repo to a wiki](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/publish-repo-to-wiki?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)"?